# Whether a thread in WAITING state can be in indefinite waiting

Tags: java, unix, process, corba

We have a multi threaded java based corba server application and one of the thread is responsible for receiving notifications being sent from other application through corba invocation.

The problem is that the notifications are not being processed through the application responsible for sending is sending the notifications.

I have taken several thread dumps using jstack and observed the following threads in the same WAITING state in all the jstacks. I know that the first thread which is a worker thread created by VC broker will signals the second thread (NotificationConsumer thread). But my doubt is the first thread (shown first below) which is in WAITING state on a Object monitor probably on a unix process which is spanned from the receiveBatchEvent() method. Incase the unix process became defunct process, will the thread be in WAITING mode forever ?

```
 "VBJ ThreadPool Worker id=4 se=unsecure scm=iiop_tp orb=419d05" daemon prio=3 tid=0x087c3c00 lwp=62 nid=0x3e in Object.wait() [0xea6ee000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:115)
    - locked <0xf3495028> (a java.lang.UNIXProcess)
    at com.ericsson.nms.fm.ims.eim.plugin.NrmNotificationConsumer.receiveBatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.ericsson.nms.cif.na.server.SequencePushConsumerImpl.push_structured_events(SequencePushConsumerImpl.java:45)
    at org.omg.CosNotifyComm.SequencePushConsumerPOA._invoke(SequencePushConsumerPOA.java:60)
    at org.omg.CosNotifyComm.SequencePushConsumerPOA._invoke(SequencePushConsumerPOA.java:40)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.poa.POAImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.poa.ActivationRecord.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.GiopProtocolAdapter.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.IIOP.ServerProtocolAdapter.doRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.GIOP.GiopProtocolAdapter.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.TPDispatcherImpl$TPDispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.inprise.vbroker.orb.ThreadPool$PoolWorker.run(Unknown Source)    

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 nid=0x28 in Object.wait() [0xeae9d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
        at com.ericsson.nms.fm.ims.eim.plugin.NrmNotificationConsumer$NotificationConsumer.synchronizedWait(Unknown Source)
        - locked <0xf32815a0> (a com.ericsson.nms.fm.ims.eim.plugin.NrmNotificationConsumer$NotificationConsumer)
        at com.ericsson.nms.fm.ims.eim.plugin.NrmNotificationConsumer$NotificationConsumer.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

Answer (score 1):

A Java thread that's waiting for a lock will wait indefinitely until the lock is released, yes. It will be waiting on a Java lock, not on anything directly involved with a UNIX process. If you have a `synchronized` block or method somewhere that spawns a UNIX process, then it'll be down to whatever code is in that block or method as to what happens if the UNIX process dies, but certainly it would be possible for the code just to block for ever.

If you have something like

```
public class SomeClass {

    public synchronized void methodA() {
        while (true) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }

    public synchronized void methodB() {
        //do something useful
    }

}
```

and one thread invokes `methodA()` on an instance of `SomeClass`, it'll acquire the lock, and never release it. If a second thread tries to invoke `methodB()` on that same instance, it'll block for ever because it won't be able to acquire the lock.

It's critically important, when you write `synchronized` blocks, that they should be as short and as fast as possible, and that they should be checked very carefully to ensure that they will always terminate.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. What I'm still unclear is that whether we can say from the jstack of the first thread (VBJ ThreadPool Worker id=4 se=unsecure scm=iiop_tp orb=419d05" daemon prio=3 tid=0x087c3c00 lwp=62 nid=0x3e) that, whether it's in indefinite WAITING state. The same thread stack is appeared in several jstacks taken in the time interval of 1 hour at the time of problem.

Comment: @ViswamDevireddyvijay You can't infer that from that output, no. Nothing will be able to tell you for certain whether it'll wait indefinitely. It's waiting for a lock to be released; but you'd need to look at the code to work out whether the code that has the lock might ever release it.